# FilmRoll loading an extra <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using FilmRoll from **straydogstudio** to slide paintings on my art society's website. Painting URLs are assembled from an array loaded in a head file and written into the html in the `"film_roll"<div>`.
js code is:
`var SliderContent=""`
`for (var i=0; i<totalRows; i+=1)`
`SliderContent = SliderContent+'<div><a href="' + imagelist[i][painting] + '"><img src="' + imagelist[i][thumbnail] + '" border="1" height="150px"></img></a></div>';`

FilmRoll startup is:
`$(document).ready(function () {`
`$(function() {`
`fr = new FilmRoll({`
`container: '#film_roll',`
`height: 150`  
           })
       })
    })`

and html is:
`...`
`<div id="film_roll">`
`<script>document.write(SliderContent);</script>`
`</div>`
`...`

This produces a sliding row of painting thumbnails *but* it prepends a `<div>` containing the text `document.write(SliderContent);` and slides it along with the images. This text is repeated at the start of every loop of the images.
If I comment out the FilmRoll startup code I get a column of painting thumbnails (as expected, with no sliding) but *without* the text in the extra `<div>`, so the FilmRoll startup is causing the problem but I can't figure out how it's doing it or how to stop it.
Anybody got any ideas?
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just experimented with FilmRoll and possibly found a workaround - instead of

```
<div id="film_roll">
  <script>document.write(SliderContent);</script>
</div>
```

just have as html the empty container

```
<div id="film_roll">
</div>
```

And change your code to an adjusted version of this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var imagelist = [ /* place your images here */ ];
  var SliderContent=""; 
  for (var i=0; i<imagelist.length; i+=1){
    SliderContent = SliderContent+'<div><a href="' + imagelist[i] + '">
                    <img src="' + imagelist[i] + '" border="1" height="150px">
                    </img></a></div>';
  }
  $("#film_roll").append(SliderContent);

  fr = new FilmRoll({
    container: '#film_roll',
    height: 150 });
});
```

With "adjusted version" following is meant: obviously, your `imagelist` contains images/elements with `thumbnails` and `paintings`. For this example I've only added some dummy images in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2jk2kc4/) (without thumbnail / paintings as part of the `imagelist` object) so you have to adjust this.
As I also don't know the variable `totalRows` in your `for`, loop, I've just replaced it with the length of the imagelist (= the amount of images in this list).

As I don't know if there is any online resource for FilmRoll, I've copied the whole filmroll.js inside the Fiddle and placed the adjusted code at the bottom below the comment `/* your code here */`.

The main adjustment is not to have the `<script>` writing the SliderContent inside the `div` as this obviously leads to issues with FilmRoll. Instead, just append the `SliderContent` using `$("#film_roll").append(SliderContent);` after the `for` loop that appends the images from the `imagelist` to the `SliderContent` and then initialise the `FilmRoll`.

Comment: matthias, you're a genius! That is the answer.

Comment: matthias, thanks very much for your help, it's much appreciated.  I thought there must be a way of writing to the DOM without using html but I didn't know how to do it. Your solution is so simple.

Comment: I found some remarks yesterday about document.write on http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html which casts this function in a very poor light, advising that it not be used. It says "... If document.write is called before the onload event, it appends or inserts text into the page ..." which is just what happened in this case. It didn't offer any workaround for the problem though.